# Returning generic object from function

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-parameter

I am writing a function for adding metrics to our service and I want to make it generic so that it can be used for different types of metrics. I don't want to do any weird casting so I thought of just making the function generic like this:

```
public <T extends Metric> T addMetric(String key,
        Function<MetricRegistry, T> metricProducer) {
    MetricRegistry registry = SharedMetricRegistries.tryGetDefault();

    Metric m = metricProducer.apply(registry);
    registry.register(key, m);

    return m;
}
```

However it won't work because of "incompatible types" which I find quite odd.
It states that it requires `T` but found `Metric` on the return, but isn't `T` already defined as a `Metric` acording to the type parameter?

Comment: change `Metric m = metricProducer.apply(registry);` to `T m = metricProducer.apply(registry);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
public <T extends Metric> T addMetric(String key,
        Function<MetricRegistry, T> metricProducer)
```

To

```
public <T extends Metric> Metric addMetric(String key,Function<MetricRegistry, T> metricProducer)
```

Or Change

```
Metric m = metricProducer.apply(registry);
```

To

```
T m = metricProducer.apply(registry);
```

Both will work.